# Python 3: Function "A list with the strings and their index"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

Write a function, which would return a list with the strings and their index.  e.g. `['good', 'morning']` -> `['0 - good', '1 - morning']`

I tried this:

```
def add_index(list_a):

    x = []
    for word in list_a:
        x = [list_a.index(word) for word in list_a]

    return x
```

However, the return is `[0, 1]`, not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate) function:

```
>>> def f(data):
...     return ['{} - {}'.format(i, s) for i, s in enumerate(data)]
... 
>>> f(['good', 'morning'])
['0 - good', '1 - morning']
```

If you are in python 3.6+ you can also use [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals):

```
>>> def f(data):
...     return [f'{i} - {s}' for i, s in enumerate(data)]
... 
>>> f(['good', 'morning'])
['0 - good', '1 - morning']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = []
for word in list_a:
    x = [list_a.index(word) + ' - ' + word  for word in list_a]

return x
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list comprehension is only pulling the index and not the word:

```
x = ["{} - {}".format(list_a.index(word), word) for word in list_a]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
for index, word in enumerate(list_a):
    print(str(index) + " - " + word)
```

This will add an index number for every topic in list_a. That index is then added into a string printing it. If you want it to be added to a new list I would do like this.

```
x = []
for index, word in enumerate(list_a):
    x.insert(len(x), str(index) + " - " + str(word))
```